# How to create multiple custom filters within a single module in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm following [this tutorial](http://danielcsgomes.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-filter-with-angularjs-v1/#.UkpHRtJmwaA) and created the underneath custom filters accordingly. The last one however causes the first one to disappear; when you use the `truncate` filter it an exception. How do you create multiple filters within a module?

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('truncate', function () {
    return function (text, length, end) {
        if (isNaN(length))
            length = 10;

        if (end === undefined)
            end = "...";

        if (text.length <= length || text.length - end.length <= length) {
            return text;
        }
        else {
            return String(text).substring(0, length-end.length) + end;
        }

    };
});


angular.module('filters', []).filter('escape', function () {
    return function(text) {
      encodeURIComponent(text);  
    };
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter("truncate", function() {})
                             .filter("escape", function() {});
```

Comment: How would you do the same but with a separate file for each filter?

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question, I guess it would be:    `angular.module('filters', [])`  `angular.module('filters').filter("truncate", function() {});`   `angular.module('filters').filter("escape", function() {});`

Answer (score 4):

The second one should be declared using

```
angular.module('filters').filter(....)
```

syntax.

The syntax you are using creates a new module everytime.

Comment: Thanks that solved it. It would have been nice they mentioned that somewhere. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Actually it is there in developer guide http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module under `Create vs Retrieval` section

Comment: I think you only would know that page when you already know the answer. Otherwise you're just thinking wtf It should say there in http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module or an example where they make two filters

Comment: Agreed, but this should also make you inquisitive about what is this syntax about,and hence explore the documentation :)

Comment: I did, for 1.5 hour :(

Comment: Cannot blame documentation for API. Look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module, it clearly mentions the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

One way to separate the filters out into individual files would be to create a filter module that requires the filters individually:

```
// init.js
angular.module('application', ['application.filters'])  

// filters.js    
angular.module('application.filters', [
               'filters.currencyCents',
               'filters.percentage',
               ]);  


// percentage.js        
angular.module('filters.percentage', []).filter('percentage', function() {
  return function(decimal, sigFigs) {
    ...
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('filters')
  .filter({
    groupBy: ['$parse', groupByFilter],
    countBy: [countByFilter]
  });

//function to handle the filter
function groupByFilter($parse) {
  return function(input) {
    ...
  }
}
```