# Call a function declared in a custom angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a declared function from my filter module:

```
filterModule.filter({
    functionFilterOne: ['CustomService', functionIDOne],
    functionFilterTwo: ['CustomService', functionIDTwo],   
});

    function functionIDOne(id) {
      return function(id) {
       return id + "PREFIXOne";
      }
    }
    function functionIDTwo(id) {
      return function(id) {
       return id + "PREFIXTwo";
      }
    }
```

In html :

```
{{  elet.id | functionFilterOne: functionIDOne}}
```

I would like to create a generic filter module for the app that containe many filter.

I don't know how to call it correctly in my html, any idea.
I got the error :

> angular.js:13283 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   functionFilterOneProvider <- functionFilterOne<-

I followed the links [Link for separate filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107899/how-to-create-multiple-custom-filters-within-a-single-module-in-angularjs) and [link filter with many function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107899/how-to-create-multiple-custom-filters-within-a-single-module-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at creating multiple filters doesn't look anything like the answer you linked to.

This is what creating filters looks like:

```
filterModule.filter('functionFilterOne', ['CustomService', functionIDOne])
            .filter('functionFilterTwo', ['CustomService', functionIDTwo]);
```

You've also made it impossible to use your custom service by shadowing it with the filter's parameter. Use different parameter names:

```
function functionIDOne(customService) {
  return function(id) {
    return id + "PREFIXOne";
  }
}
```

Comment: Just another issue , i tried to call a method in CustomService from the functionIDOne function and i got an error that CustomService  is not defined, how can pass this service to my function?

Comment: @selma It's probably because you are shadowing the function parameter that contains the service. Use different parameter names (see the update to my answer).

Comment: thx worked very well , can i ask you an other question, when i called the service with customService.getNameById(id).then(function(rslt){
console.log( rslt.name);
return rslt.name;

});
console.log print the name but arriving in html empty, have you an idea?

Comment: @selma Did you remember to put a `return` at the beginning of that?

Comment: yes i added it like this:function functionIDOne(customService) {
  return function(id) {
    return 
 
 customService.getNameById(id).then(function(rslt){ console.log( rslt.name); return rslt.name; });
 
  }
} and it return '{}' but in console there is the name, in htnl is {{  elmt.id | getNameById}}

Comment: @selma Looks like returning a promise in a filter doesn't work. Promises are for quick data transformations. Not asynchronous ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864318/angular-how-use-http-in-a-filter

Comment: i tried the stateful filter as follows but it doesn't return any thing :
function functionIDOne(customService) {
  return function(id) {
    return 
 
 customService.getNameById(id).then(function(rslt){ console.log( rslt.name); return rslt.name; });
  getNameById.$stateful = true;
 return getNameById;
  }
} 

can you help me , i'm new with angular and i need a support

Comment: @selma The comments section of my answer is not the place to troubleshoot this. I have answered the matter that your question was about. Please create a new question for these additional issues so that more than one person can try to help you.

Comment: Ok, i will create another one separatly

Answer (score 1):

just simple

```
AppModule.filter('addprifix', function () {
    return function (input)
    {
        return input + "PREFIXOne";
    }
});
```

Use like  `ng-model="id|addprifix"`

Comment: yes you are rigth, i want to have one module that containes many functions and each functions are declared with a specific services.

Comment: than `AppModule` Replace with your module and declare custom filter